# My Led doesn't increase its uptime even I added delay after digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW);

Tags: arduino

So I have an PIR motion sensor, and a led. Once a motion is detected, the led will light up. It is lighting up and all, but the led's uptime duration is only 5 seconds. I want to increase it by 5 so it will be 10 seconds uptime when motion is detected.

I already added delay(5000); after digitalWrite(ledpin,LOW); to add 5 seconds delay before the led will turn off but it is still 5 seconds instead of 10 seconds

```
//the time we give the sensor to calibrate (10-60 secs according to the 
datasheet)
int calibrationTime = 30;       

//the time when the sensor outputs a low impulse
long unsigned int lowIn;        

//the amount of milliseconds the sensor has to be low
//before we assume all motion has stopped
long unsigned int pause = 10000; 

boolean lockLow = true;
boolean takeLowTime; 

int pirPin = 10;    //the digital pin connected to the PIR sensor's output
int ledPin = 13;


//SETUP
void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(pirPin, INPUT);
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(pirPin, LOW);

//give the sensor some time to calibrate
Serial.print("calibrating sensor ");
for(int i = 0; i < calibrationTime; i++){
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(1000);
  }
Serial.println(" done");
Serial.println("SENSOR ACTIVE");
delay(50);
}

 //LOOP
void loop(){

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == HIGH){
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
   if(lockLow){ 
     //makes sure we wait for a transition to LOW before any further output is made:
     lockLow = false;           
     Serial.println("---");
     Serial.print("motion detected at ");
     Serial.print(millis()/1000);
     Serial.println(" sec");
     delay(50);
     }        
     takeLowTime = true;
   }

 if(digitalRead(pirPin) == LOW){    
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  //the led visualizes the sensors output pin state
 ///////////////I added delay below by 5 seconds but nothing changed
   delay(5000);


   if(takeLowTime){
    lowIn = millis();          //save the time of the transition from high to LOW
    takeLowTime = false;       //make sure this is only done at the start of a LOW phase
    }
   //if the sensor is low for more than the given pause,
   //we assume that no more motion is going to happen
   if(!lockLow && millis() - lowIn > pause){ 
       //makes sure this block of code is only executed again after
       //a new motion sequence has been detected
       lockLow = true;                       
       Serial.print("motion ended at ");      //output
       Serial.print((millis() - pause)/1000);
       Serial.println(" sec");
       delay(50);
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: You need to put the delay before you switch off your LED

Comment: already tried, didn't work

Comment: Where did you put the delay? Did you get any errors? Also, since you stated that your LED is lit up for 5 seconds, but I can't find any delays or timers for that, I assume that your PIR fires for 5 seconds at a time when detection motion. Can you confirm this?

Comment: when I did what you said, what happened is, yes it added 5 seconds and became 10 seconds before the led turned off. but after it turned off, when I try to gesture a motion in front of the pir sensor, I still need to wait also 10 seconds before it lights up again

Comment: Try to put the delay after `Serial.print("motion detected at ");
     Serial.print(millis()/1000);
     Serial.println(" sec");` Hope that helps!

Comment: Since there is no 10 second timeout somewhere in the code, this is very likely your PIR set to a 10 second timeout. In many PIR breakout boards, there are two values one can set: Pulse Time and Timeout Length. Pulse Time is the time duration, the signal gets pulled high when motion is detected and Timeout Length is the time duration a new pulse is inhibited, even when motion is detected. Check your datasheet how to change these values.